# Have one attribute passed to another attribute on the same Backbone model

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone model named Summary which has attributes Total and DisplayTotal. What I would like to do is simply duplicate the value of Total and pass it to DisplayTotal.

Also is it possible to set a default for DisplayTotal?

```
defaults:{
    "DisplayTotal" : this.Total,
}
```

If possible, as soon as the Total attribute is set, it should set its value to DisplayTotal too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are against this approach.

#### P.1. `defaults` is interpreted in Class definition time

So `this` shouldn't be what you expect, probably `this` would be `window` or something like this.

#### P.2. Backbone attributes are accessed through the `Model.get()` function

So your example is not correct it should be something like:

```
defaults:{
  "DisplayTotal" : this.get( "Total" ),
}
```

But point **P.1.** is still making this to not work.

You have also a list of approaches to achieve want you want:

#### S.1. Initialize `DisplayTotal` in `Model.initialize()`

```
initialize: function(){
  this.set( "DisplayTotal", this.get( "Total" ) );
}
```

#### S.2. Delay the `DisplayTotal` initialization to *run time*

```
defaults:{
  "DisplayTotal" : function() { return this.get( "Total" ) }
}
```

Very danger solution, and probably you would have *context* problems with that `this`.

#### S.3. Update `DisplayTotal` anytime `Total` is updated

```
initialize: function(){
  this.on( "change:Total", this.setDisplayTotal, this );
},

setDisplayTotal: function(){
  this.set( "DisplayTotal", this.get( "Total" ) );
}
```

But I'm affraid you should combine this one with the **S.1.** due I don't think the event `change` is triggered in the first set of the attributes.